# Qt 4.8 GUI on embedded Linux System

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt4, qml, embedded-linux

I'm working on a GUI running on an embedded Linux Board with following specs:

- CPU: ATSAMA5D31 500Mhz
- RAM: 1024 MBit
- 5" 800x480 Cap Touchscreen

My Board is connect via Ethernet to some other Boards and is used to controll and visualize these Boards - so all data i have to visualize is comming via Ethernet.
All Menues, Information,... is dynamic so the GUI has to built up dynamically.

I experimented with different Methods auf GUI with Qt.

1. QML Objects created, managed and updatet with C++
2. Quick GUI which generates dynamic QML Objects
3. Widgets GUI with different Windows and Customized Widgets

I'm unhappy with all 3 of this options.

1. It's really slow (storing and managing the objects in C++ is very fast - but creation of the QML Objects and also updating takes allot of time)
2. Was fast at the Beginning but gets slower with each line JS added
3. Customizing the Widgets is not as confortable as defining QML Elements for me

**My Question now: which is the best method for programming an efficient and dynamic GUI with Qt?**

I searched allot - but most of the threads i found rellied to Desktop programms.

Comment: Have you tried customizing widgets with css?

Comment: Jep, currently im experimenting with widgets und custom css.